# Get HTML area tag name from Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, dictionary, google-visualization, area

I would like to display area tag name after a person clicks on it. Unfortunately when I use code below for map area I get undefined name of obiekt name. It's weird because for textbox 'kot' it works well.

```
<script>

function metoda(obiekt)
{
    alert(obiekt.name); //Here I get undefined!
}

</script>

<input type='text' value='kot' name='das' onclick='metoda(this);'></input>
<map name='mapkama'>
   <area 
      name='AE' 
      shape='POLY' 
      coords='285,87,287,90,288,87,285,87' 
      href='#'  
      title='' 
      onclick='metoda(this); return false;'>
</map>

<img usemap="#mapkama" src='http://myimage.com/image'>
```

How to display area name from metoda function?

Comment: unfortunately, the area cannot be clicked unless it has a visible element.

Comment: @rob I've added the part with visible element, hope this help you to help me ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using jquery you can achieve this by

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 

function metoda(obiekt) 
{ 
    alert(obiekt.getAttribute("name")); 
} 

</script> 

<input type='text' value='kot' name='das' onclick='metoda(this);'></input> 

<img src="planets.gif" width="145" height="126" alt="Planets" usemap="#planetmap" />

<map name="planetmap">
  <area name='AE1' shape="rect" coords="0,0,82,126" href="#" alt="Sun" onclick='metoda(this); return false;'/>
</map>
```

Comment: hi I have edited my answer, `obiekt.getAttribute("name")` should do it.

Answer (score 1):

The below code returns me the value of the name properly.

```
<script> 

function metoda(obiekt) 
{ 
    alert(obiekt.name); 
} 

</script> 

<input type='text' value='kot' name='das' onclick='metoda(this);'></input> 

<img src="planets.gif" width="145" height="126" alt="Planets" usemap="#planetmap" />

<map name="planetmap">
  <area name='AE1' shape="rect" coords="0,0,82,126" href="#" alt="Sun" onclick='metoda(this); return false;'/>
</map>
```

Only difference is that, I am using a rect shape whereas you are using poly. Can you check if using rect or circle help you.

Comment: this still returns undefined.

Comment: You mean for the rect, it returns undefined? One thing I noticed, that the poly shape co-ordinates need to be proper in order to get click co-ordinates

Comment: @Sachin Shanbhag The same as for rob - undefined. I've updated my source code to the real life scenario I have, so you will be able to reproduce it easily

Comment: Or better not because it's a bunch of code. This example is enough I think

Comment: @tomaszs - I am able to get the value AE as output on running above modified code. If this helps, I am using IE8 version 8.0.6001.18702 browser.